# Visual studio 2017 Professional setup operation failed

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2017

I try to install visual studio 2017 professional but I got error 'Professional setup operation failed'. When I click on  *viewing log* I saw a huge list of Incomplete workloads and components. Should I search for every each of this items and download them?

And here is the log :

> The product failed to install the listed workloads and components due
>   to one or more package failures.
>
> Incomplete workloads
>       .NET desktop development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop,version=15.0.26208.0)
>       ASP.NET and web development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb,version=15.0.26208.0)
>       Data storage and processing (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Data,version=15.0.26208.0)
>       Desktop development with C++ (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop,version=15.0.26228.0)
>       Game development with C++ (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeGame,version=15.0.26228.0)
>       Mobile development with .NET (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat,version=15.0.26228.0)
>       Mobile development with C++ (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeMobile,version=15.0.26228.0)
>       Visual Studio core editor (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.CoreEditor,version=15.0.26228.0)
>
> Incomplete components
>       .NET desktop development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Prerequisites,version=15.0.26208.0)
>       .NET Framework 4.6.1 development tools (Microsoft.Net.ComponentGroup.DevelopmentPrerequisites,version=15.0.26208.0)
>       .NET Portable Library targeting pack (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.PortableLibrary,version=15.0.26208.0)
>       ASP.NET and web development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Web,version=15.0.26208.0)
>       Azure Cloud Services core tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.Waverton,version=15.0.26208.0)
>       Azure Data Lake Tools (Microsoft.Component.Azure.DataLake.Tools,version=15.0.26208.0)
>       Blend for Visual Studio (Microsoft.ComponentGroup.Blend,version=15.0.26208.0)
>       C# and Visual Basic (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.LanguageServices,version=15.0.26208.0)
>       C++ Android development tools (Component.MDD.Android,version=15.0.26208.0)
>       C++ profiling tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.DiagnosticTools,version=15.0.26208.0)
>       ClickOnce Publishing (Microsoft.Component.ClickOnce,version=15.0.26208.0)
>       Cloud Explorer (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CloudExplorer,version=15.0.26208.0)
>       Connectivity and publishing tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Common.Azure.Tools,version=1.9.170119.3)
>       Data sources and service references (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VisualStudioData,version=15.0.26208.0)
>       Data sources for SQL Server support (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.DataSources,version=15.0.26208.0)
>       Developer Analytics tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.AppInsights.Tools,version=15.0.26228.0)
>       Entity Framework 6 tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.EntityFramework,version=15.0.26208.0)
>       F# language support (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.FSharp,version=15.0.26208.0)
>       Graphics debugger and GPU profiler for DirectX (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Graphics.Tools,version=15.0.26208.0)
>       IIS Express  (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.IISExpress,version=15.0.26208.0)
>       JavaScript and TypeScript language support (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.JavaScript.TypeScript,version=15.0.26208.0)
>       Managed Desktop Workload Core (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Core,version=15.0.26208.0)
>       NuGet package manager (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet,version=15.0.26208.0)
>       Profiling tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.DiagnosticTools,version=15.0.26208.0)
>       Redgate SQL Search (Component.Redgate.SQLSearch.VSExtension,version=2.3.10.1131)
>       SQL Server Data Tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.SSDT,version=15.0.26208.0)
>       Visual Studio core editor (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor,version=15.0.26208.0)
>       Web Deploy (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.WebDeploy,version=15.0.26208.0)
>       Windows Communication Foundation (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Wcf.Tooling,version=15.0.26208.0)
>       Xamarin (Component.Xamarin,version=15.0.26228.0)
>       Xamarin Workbooks (Component.Xamarin.Inspector,version=15.0.26228.0)
>
> You can search for solutions using the information below, modify your
>   selections for the above workloads and components and retry the
>   installation, or remove the product from your machine.
>
> Following is a collection of individual package failures that led to
>   the incomplete workloads and components above. To search for existing
>   reports of these specific problems, please copy and paste the URL from
>   each package failure into a web browser. If the issue has already been
>   reported, you can find solutions or workarounds there. If the issue
>   has not been reported, you can create a new issue where other people
>   will be able to find solutions or workarounds.
>
> Package
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Branding.Professional,version=15.0.26228.0,language=en-US'
>   failed to download from
>   'https://download.microsoft.com/download/8/E/E/8EED5B20-7872-4CDE-A231-E92377F9BD8C/microsoft.visualstudio.branding.professional.vsix'.
>       Search URL: ...
>
> Bits download failed: File not found.
>      WinInet download failed: Function: InternetOpenUrl, HR: -2147012889, Message: Unknown error 12007
>
> Package
>   'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.OfficeIntegration.Resources,version=15.112.26224.0,chip=x64,language=en-US'
>   failed to download from
>   'https://download.microsoft.com/download/4/7/0/47065291-F0B7-45E2-A513-956F42D65912/tfs_officeIntegrationCoreRes.msi'.
>       Search URL: ...
>           .NET desktop development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop,version=15.0.26208.0)
>           ASP.NET and web development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb,version=15.0.26208.0)
>           Data storage and processing (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Data,version=15.0.26208.0)
>           Desktop development with C++ (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop,version=15.0.26228.0)
>           Game development with C++ (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeGame,version=15.0.26228.0)
>           Mobile development with .NET (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat,version=15.0.26228.0)
>           Mobile development with C++ (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeMobile,version=15.0.26228.0)
>           Visual Studio core editor (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.CoreEditor,version=15.0.26228.0)
>       Impacted components
>           .NET desktop development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Prerequisites,version=15.0.26208.0)
>           .NET Framework 4.6.1 development tools (Microsoft.Net.ComponentGroup.DevelopmentPrerequisites,version=15.0.26208.0)
>           .NET Portable Library targeting pack (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.PortableLibrary,version=15.0.26208.0)
>           ASP.NET and web development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Web,version=15.0.26208.0)
>           Azure Cloud Services core tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.Waverton,version=15.0.26208.0)
>           Azure Data Lake Tools (Microsoft.Component.Azure.DataLake.Tools,version=15.0.26208.0)
>           Blend for Visual Studio (Microsoft.ComponentGroup.Blend,version=15.0.26208.0)
>           C# and Visual Basic (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.LanguageServices,version=15.0.26208.0)
>           C++ Android development tools (Component.MDD.Android,version=15.0.26208.0)
>           C++ profiling tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.DiagnosticTools,version=15.0.26208.0)
>           ClickOnce Publishing (Microsoft.Component.ClickOnce,version=15.0.26208.0)
>           Cloud Explorer (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CloudExplorer,version=15.0.26208.0)
>           Connectivity and publishing tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Common.Azure.Tools,version=1.9.170119.3)
>           Data sources and service references (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VisualStudioData,version=15.0.26208.0)
>           Data sources for SQL Server support (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.DataSources,version=15.0.26208.0)
>           Developer Analytics tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.AppInsights.Tools,version=15.0.26228.0)
>           Entity Framework 6 tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.EntityFramework,version=15.0.26208.0)
>           F# language support (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.FSharp,version=15.0.26208.0)
>           Graphics debugger and GPU profiler for DirectX (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Graphics.Tools,version=15.0.26208.0)
>           IIS Express  (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.IISExpress,version=15.0.26208.0)
>           JavaScript and TypeScript language support (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.JavaScript.TypeScript,version=15.0.26208.0)
>           Managed Desktop Workload Core (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Core,version=15.0.26208.0)
>           NuGet package manager (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet,version=15.0.26208.0)
>           Profiling tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.DiagnosticTools,version=15.0.26208.0)
>           Redgate SQL Search (Component.Redgate.SQLSearch.VSExtension,version=2.3.10.1131)
>           SQL Server Data Tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.SSDT,version=15.0.26208.0)
>           Visual Studio core editor (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor,version=15.0.26208.0)
>           Web Deploy (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.WebDeploy,version=15.0.26208.0)
>           Windows Communication Foundation (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Wcf.Tooling,version=15.0.26208.0)
>           Xamarin (Component.Xamarin,version=15.0.26228.0)
>           Xamarin Workbooks (Component.Xamarin.Inspector,version=15.0.26228.0)
>       Details
>           WebClient download failed: The remote name could not be resolved: 
>           Bits download failed: File not found.
>           WinInet download failed: Function: InternetOpenUrl, HR: -2147012889, Message: Unknown error 12007

Comment: *Should I search for every each of this items and download them?* No, you don't need to. The installer should take care of the dependencies.

Comment: so why i got the error?

Comment: Sounds like your internet connection is having issues.  Maybe create an offline installer.  vs_professional.exe --layout c:\vs2017offline and install from the downloaded vs 2017

Comment: actually i'm using offline installer and i have the problem

Comment: sounds like something did not download properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio 2017 installer will need to make HTTP/HTTPS requests and/or download files from the following locations (via HTTPS/HTTP or ports 443/80):

```
[https://aka.ms/vs/*][1]
[https://go.microsoft.com/*][2]
[https://download.microsoft.com/*][3]
[https://dl.xamarin.com/*][4]
[https://dl.google.com/android/*][5]
[https://archive.apache.org/dist/ant/*][6]
[http://cocos2d-x.org/filedown/start/349][7]
[https://www.python.org/ftp/python/*][8]
[https://incredibuildvs2017i.azureedge.net/*][9]
[http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/*][10]
[http://netstorage.unity3d.com/unity/*][11]
[https://download.epicgames.com/Builds/*][12]
```

The first three are critical for setup to work and most of files come from the download.microsoft.com. All the others are external components which are only necessary if the user chooses to install them.